# Performance issue while drawing multiple image in a loop on an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, drawimage

I have 100-200 distinct small images that i need to draw on an HTML5 canvas. The images are all loaded and ready to drawn.

If i call canvas.drawImage in a loop - even if it takes ~1 msec to draw an image - the total time might reach 200 msec - which is too much.

Is there anyway to get a performance boost? writing all images at once maybe?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Are all of your images moving to a new location every time you make a change to your canvas? If not, you might be able to introduce a strategy of layered canvases. What platform will this be running on? In the browser on my desktop, redrawing hundreds of images for every mouse drag event doesn't feel heavy to the user.

Comment: Please show your code -- you likely have some inefficiency there.

Comment: 1ms is exceedingly slow and thus hints at (A) you have hardware rendering disabled (B) the device you are using is very low end. As markE suggested please provide a code sample, and it will also help if you can specify the browser and hardware you are running.

Comment: @markE Where/ How? are you asking where/how you can? or where /how I can.? Will go have a look now if you are asking me to  approve. HTML-Canvas is a little quite. BTW the HTML-Canvas remarks I think need a little work. We need to be careful not to forget webGl and the soon to hit web assembly that will bring canvas to a whole new level of performance

Comment: @markE The only way I have found to approve is when editing you get a list of other edits in pink. Click on that and a new tab opens. You can approve from there. (the system is still a little buggy my way) I will have to get back to you on the remarks I am at the way to late tail end of my day.